# What is the best way to mimic the findstr functionality in c#?

Tags: c#, search, find

I am searching for several thousand strings in a large directory tree which contains several thousand files. Each string can appear in many different files. What is the most performant way to perform this search in c#? I tried proccessinfo start with findstr (but it is painfully slow, because it opens every single file several thousand times). Any suggestions?

Comment: Which OS? Maybe use the Indexing Service or Windows Search?

Comment: How are the files stored in the tree?  Are they actual File objects or are they stored in plain text?  (...or secret option number 3?) :-)

Comment: I'm searching through a very large code base for resource keys. So the file types are all varied but can be read using a StreamReader. Right now im using the Directory.GetFiles to gather the files. Right now im using the regex library to match the key to a string which contains the contents of each file. Im running on Window Server 2008.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this with C#? Why not just use findstr? You can tell it to execute against entire directory trees, after all.

Comment: I was using findstr. But because im interested in where each string occurs, i have to execute find str several thousand times per file which takes roughly 30 seconds per string (this adds up quickly). I wanted to reduce the time to execute by only opening each file once. Right now its at about 1 second per file.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a widget that indexes your file tree using Lucene.NET.  Once the documents are indexed you can then use all of Lucene's power to search through the content in a very powerful way...without having to open each file 1000's of time!  :P

Not sure about the life of the program...this may not be a good idea for a one time use scenario.  And for a multi-use scenario you will need to make sure that you have a windows service that updates your index as the files change over time (if that is important).

This will be very performant once the indexes are created!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to perform a one-time search or continually on demand?  I would suggest either tying into the Indexing service or implement your own Lucene indexing.  There are a quite a few open-source implementations of the Lucene indexing, where basically you scan your files once and build a comprehensive index of the contents and then future searches are made against the premade index.  The index generation takes a while, but the searches are very fast.  This works well for 'web' type content and simply phrases and words.

If you're trying to find non-word/arbitrary random strings, then you've got a different task.

-Jeff